# difference between 0.5 and 1/2 during integration

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to compute the next integral with x in power of 0.5. It is done by Mathematica:
[image]

What is strange about this calculation is that numbers don't represent where they came from (for instance, what is 0.0176839?)

As soon as I write (1/2) instead of "0.5" in the power of x, i get this:
[image]

What is the difference between 0.5 and 1/2 that can influence on integration?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

It's one of the vagarities of the symbolic solver. The 0.5 goes down the route of giving you a solution that has a similar form as if you raised it to the power of 0.12 (or any other decimal number). The solution that you get when you specify 1/2 is a special case of the more general one that was given before.